# Are there lifecycle callback functions for javascript objects such as array & string

Tags: javascript, object, callback, lifecycle

Ok guys I've been messing about with prototypes for a while now and am not ready to give up on their usefulness just yet... despite heavy criticism!

I'm battling the age old problem of `Object.prototype` property inheritance in other objects such as arrays & strings. ie:

```
Object.defineProperty(
    Object.prototype, 'jsf',
    {get:function(){
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }};
);

x = {abc: 123};
y = document.createElement('div');
```

If you're reading this page, and you are!, then you will know that because both `x` & `y` are objects, based on `typeof x` or `y`, both `x` & `y` will inherit the `jsf` property, ergo:

```
x.jsf = {"abc": 123}
y.jsf = Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Now I know there are various work-rounds like:

```
Object.defineProperty(y, 'jsf', {value: void 0});
```

And my favorite:

```
function Master_Object(){ this.jsf = JSON.stringify(this) }
function Master_Element(){ this.str = this.outerHTML }

Object.defineProperty(
    Object.prototype, 'ms',
    {get:function(){
        cons=this.constructor.name;
        if(cons=='Object')                  return new Master_Object();
            else if(cons=='HTMLDivElement') return new Master_Element();
    }}
);
```

Where every object only has 1 manageable custom property, `.ms`, and that property is an object containing properties specific to the objects constructor, thus:

```
x.ms.jsf = {"abc": 123}
y.ms.jsf = undefined

y.ms.str = <div></div>
x.ms.str = undefined
```

Favorite or not I don't want to have to type the prefix `.ms`, it's untidy and frankly in the way!

I've been playing with custom elements and I know about the life-cycle callbacks, and how they track the progression of an element...

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

proto.createdCallback = function() {...};
proto.attachedCallback = function() {...};

var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {prototype: proto});
```

Thing is I can't seem to translate these callbacks to be used on an object scope as opposed to an element scope?!

It would save me a lot of hassle if I could just write something along these lines:

```
Object.defineProperty(
    Object.prototype, 'createdCallback',
    {value: function(){
        var Proto_Clone = Object.create(Object.prototype);
        var cons = this.constructor.name;
        if(cons == 'Object'){
            Object.defineProperty(Proto_Clone,'...',{value:...});
        }
            else if (cons == ...)   ...;
        this.prototype = Proto_Clone;
    }}
);
```

The idea being that when an object is instantiated, a check is performed on it to ascertain it's constructor and if the said constructor is `Object` then it's prototype is changed to the modified `Proto_Clone` before it is parsed.

That way the original `Object.prototype` is never modified and there is no leakage of properties from  one object to the next...???!!!

So what do YOU think ? Is it possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You could use try/catch:

```
Object.defineProperty(
    Object.prototype, 'jsf',
    {get:function(){
        try {
            return JSON.stringify(this);
        } catch (e) {
            return undefined;
        }
    }};
);
```

Comment: sorry dude, it still leaves me with an undefined `.jsf` property floating around all my objects... and I can avoid that myself.